# PropertyChangedCallback of DependencyProperty Ignores Delay Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control with a textbox and a custom list control that's basically a ListBox with a CollectionView. I'd like to use the filter functionality of the CollectionView and use the text from the textbox to filter the visible elements.

A simplified representation of the xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterTextControl"/>
<CustomControls:OverviewControl
    x:Name="ProfileOverviewControl"
    FilterText="{Binding ElementName=FilterTextControl, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay, Delay=5000}"
    Items="{Binding AllItems}"/>
```

The CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedProfiles"
                  Source="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:OverviewControl}}"
                  Filter="GroupedProfiles_OnFilter">
<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Location" />
    <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
</CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Location" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The FilterText Dependency Property in the OverviewControl:

```
public string FilterText
{
    get => (string)GetValue(FilterTextProperty);
    set => SetValue(FilterTextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FilterText), typeof(string), 
    typeof(ProfileOverviewControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFilterTextChanged));

private static void OnFilterTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var intanceOfThisClass = (ProfileOverviewControl)d;
        if (_collectionViewSource == null) 
        _collectionViewSource = intanceOfThisClass.FindResource("GroupedProfiles") as CollectionViewSource;
     _collectionViewSource?.View?.Refresh();
}
```

The OnFilterEvent method:

```
    private void GroupedProfiles_OnFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterText) || e.Item.ToString().Contains(FilterText);
    }
```

**The Problem**

As you can see in the binding of the FilterText I have a delay of 5000ms. For testing purposes I've made it 5000ms instead of a reasonable 500ms.
In order for the filter to work I need to refresh the CollectionView.
However the PropertyChangedCallback fires immediately after each change instead of throttling it with the delay binding.

I don't quite understand this behaviour. If this is just how a delay binding works, are there alternatives for throttling the CollectionView refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing the bindings like this. This way the delay will be on the textbox change. Now the delay is on the filter property change (if changed from the OverviewControl).

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterTextControl" Text="{Binding ElementName=ProfileOverviewControl, Path=FilterText, Delay=5000}"/>
<CustomControls:OverviewControl
    x:Name="ProfileOverviewControl"
    Items="{Binding AllItems}"/>
```

Comment: What a great idea! Very simple and does exactly what I want!